# Reducing the laborious Sturm's method under a certain consideration.

Tags: polynomials, proof-explanation, systems-of-equations

I was studying about "Sturm's method for location of real roots". There was an assertion given which said that:

> If at any stage we obtain a function Is $f(x)$ such that all of its roots are
> complex, then the $\gcd$ process need not be continued further and the
> determination and location of real roots will be possible from the set of
> functions $f(x),f_1(x),...,f_s(x)$, because $f_s(x)$ retains the same sign for
> all values of $x$ and no alteration in the number of changes of sign can
> take place in the sequence of functions beyond $f_s(x)$.

I didn't get how they asserted the fact that "no alteration in the number of changes of sign can take place in the sequence of functions beyond $f_s(x)$"? I am not quite getting it...

Answer (score 0):

Consider the tail $f_s(x),\, f_{s+1}(x),\, \ldots, f_n(x)$ of the Sturm sequence. The construction of Sturm sequences is designed so that as $x$ varies continuously, the total number of sign changes of this subsequence only changes if one of the functions on the end ($f_s(x)$ or $f_n(x)$) changes sign. The last function $f_n(x)$ is a constant by construction, and the $f_s(x)$ does not change sign since all of its roots are complex. Hence the number of sign changes of the tail $f_s(x),\, f_{s+1}(x),\, \ldots f_n(x)$ does not vary as $x$ ranges over the real numbers.